# How to split a list into sublists based on value?

Tags: python

I get a python list like this:

```
['#main', '89631139', '22804410', '38517737', '#extra', '43228023', '56532353', '!side', '22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to separate this list in sublists based on values of *spliters* which are : "#main", "#extra" and "!side".
I also need to exclude those *spliters*.

Here, the output should be:

```
main = ['89631139', '22804410', '38517737']
extra = ['43228023', '56532353']
side = ['22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']
```

I want to avoid to code more than one loop for this (it might even be possible to do it without a loop) but I don't fine an elegant way to do this.

Could you help me guys ?

Comment: You say your splitters include `"!split"`, but your data includes `'!side'`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 6):

You can group on a condition (such as entry is a number) using the builtin [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

original = ['#main', '89631139', '22804410', '38517737', '#extra', '43228023', '56532353', '!side', '22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']

# since it provides the three lists and you know that ahead of time, you can unpack into each

main, extra, side = [list(g) for m, g in itertools.groupby(original, key=lambda x: x.isnumeric()) if m]
```

Then each list is assigned, result:

```
In [22]: main
Out[22]: ['89631139', '22804410', '38517737']

In [23]: extra
Out[23]: ['43228023', '56532353']

In [24]: side
Out[24]: ['22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']
```

Answer (score 3):

Just find the indices and take the slices:

```py
data=['#main', '89631139', '22804410', '38517737', '#extra', '43228023', '56532353', '!side', '22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']


mainIndex, extraIndex, sideIndex = (data.index(item) for item in ('#main', '#extra', '!side'))

main, extra, side = data[mainIndex+1:extraIndex], data[extraIndex+1:sideIndex], data[sideIndex+1:]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
main
['89631139', '22804410', '38517737']
extra
['43228023', '56532353']
side
['22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding one more option via string manipulation.

```
import re
main, extra, side = [i.strip(',').split(',') for i in re.split(
    r"#main|#extra|!side", ','.join(l))[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match any number of splitters with this.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
# Change this regex to get the pattern you are looking for
key_pattern = re.compile(r'^(#|!)([a-z]+)') 

original = ['#main', '89631139', '22804410', '38517737', '#extra', '43228023', '56532353', '!side', '22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']

for item in original: 
    if key_pattern.search(item): 
        k = key_pattern.search(item).group(2) 
    else: 
        result[k].append(item)

print(result)

# Gather results
main, extra, side = result['main'], result['extra'], result['side']
```

Print output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'main': ['89631139', '22804410', '38517737'], 'extra': ['43228023', '56532353'], 'side': ['22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']})
```

Comment: If you have Python 3.8, You can use the Walrus operator in the `if` condition to store the value if True.

Answer (score -1):

With a single `for` loop as you wanted.

```
l = ['#main', '89631139', '22804410', '38517737', '#extra', '43228023', '56532353', '!side', '22804410', '45467446', '31801517', '63767246']
main = []
extra = []
side = []

flag = ''
for i in l:
    if i in ['#main', '#extra', '!side']:
        # set the flag to the second letter of the string
        flag = i[1]
    else:
        if flag == 'm': 
            main.append(i)
        elif flag == 'e':
            extra.append(i)
        elif flag == 's':
            side.append(i)
```